# Parameters.AddWithValue does not replace my value

Tags: c#, sql

Trying to run a SQL query and I were told to use Parameters to avoid SQLInjection. So I'm playing around with parameterized query. But it's not going so good.

This is my code:

```
using (_cmd = _connection.CreateCommand())
{
    _connection.Open();
    _cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username`= '@username'";
    _cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", _username);
}
```

As I understand it @username will be replaced with my username field. But this is not the case, not sure what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've turned the parameter into a string literal in your query.

Remove the apostrophes from around `@username`:

```
_cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username`= @username";
```

Answer (score 3):

Remove the quotes from `'@username'` else it will be treated as a string literal.

```
_cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username`= @username";
```